# How to add a string in between consecutive lines starting with the same word?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with interchanging lines starting with 'WordNode' and 'gloss word' but sometimes there are duplicate lines starting with 'gloss word':

```
WordNode"a'inai"
gloss word "repose"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "running"
gloss word "turned on"
gloss word "active"
WordNode "aitco"
gloss word "Armenian"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ethereal"
gloss word "ether"
```

I'd like to be able to add the previous wordNode... line to each duplicate lines starting with 'gloss word':

```
WordNode "a'inai"
gloss word "repose"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "running"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "turned on"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "active"
WordNode "aitco"
gloss word "Armenian"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ethereal"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ether"
```

I tried this

```
sed -r ':a; N; /(gloss word)[^\n]*\n\1/ s/\n.*//; ta; P; D' file1.txt > file2.txt
```

but it just keeps the first and delete the following duplicate lines. what would be the correct way to do this using sed awk or any other regular expression?

Comment: You commented  `But this doesn't change the data at all` in my answer. What does it mean? you are seeing no output for the `Awk` command which I gave?

Comment: @Inian that seems strange... even dos style line ending wouldn't affect... OP indeed has to clarify

Comment: by "this doesn't change the data at all" i meant no alteration is done on the data in running your code. I wanted to try it again but it's deleted. I thought @suddeep's answer is the same as yours, trying that strips out lines starting with wordnodes and leave lines starting with gloss word. I am a newbie for this regular expressions maybe I have made a mistake. :/ luckily, potong's answer do it exactly as I wanted. Thank you all!

Comment: @BitTad the `awk` answers given all work as expected for your example input... either you made a mistake in trying it or something strange with `awk` version you have... in any case, if you are satisfied with potong's answer, you should mark it as accepted... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/WordNode/h;//d;x;p;x' file
```

Store the line containing `WordNode` in the hold space (HS) and then delete it. For all other lines i.e. line containing `gloss word`, swap to the HS, print the HS and then revert to the pattern space (PS) and print that.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '/^WordNode/{header=$0; p=0} p{print header} /^gloss word/{p=1} 1' file

WordNode"a'inai"
gloss word "repose"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "running"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "turned on"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "active"
WordNode "aitco"
gloss word "Armenian"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ethereal"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ether"
```

Comment: golfed... `awk '/^gloss word/{print h; print} /^WordNode/{h=$0}'`

Comment: nice! perhaps `{if(h)print h..}` in case file starts without header

Comment: @Sundeep: Posted the same answe, some hours before (now in deleted state) OP said he is not seeing any output at all, hence the comment

Comment: @Inian inhis comment under your answer the OP didn't say he is not seeing any output, he said "this doesn't change the data". I bet he expected his original input file to be modified after the command ran.

Comment: @EdMorton: Ahh! could be, but deleted mine nevertheless. This answer is better than mine I guess! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is most easily done by a script rather than sed or awk as so:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ $line == WordNode* ]]; then wnl=$line; else echo $wnl; echo $line; fi
done << file1.txt
```

(this only echos the last `WordNode` line before the `gloss word` line, so if you expect to have multiple `WordNode` lines together, and want to echo them all, then you'd have to tweak it to be stateful)

Comment: `This is most easily done by a script rather than sed or awk as so:` - no, this is concise and trivial in awk and should NOT be done with a shell loop, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for **some** of the reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '/WordNode/{h=$0 ORS;next} {print h $0}' file
WordNode"a'inai"
gloss word "repose"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "running"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "turned on"
WordNode "akti"
gloss word "active"
WordNode "aitco"
gloss word "Armenian"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ethereal"
WordNode "aitxero"
gloss word "ether"
```